# Is it correct to upvote questions that don't deserve to have a negative score?

Tags: discussion

When a question has already a downvote, is it correct to cast an upvote only because you think that that question does not deserve a downvote? I'm talking about an upvote that you wouldn't have cast if the question hadn't got a downvote.

The problem is that sometimes questions are not so sloppy they deserve a downvote, but contextually they are not good enough to deserve an upvote.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site

Comment: Whoever want to, and will, downvote, please "consider to add a comment".

Comment: Downvoting on meta because I believe that the "pity upvote" is a bad thing.  (As indicated elsewhere, a downvote on a meta site is not the same as a downvote on a mainsite; meta up- and downvotes are used mostly to indicate agreement and disagreement with the position stated or implied.)

Comment: Assuming that the original post was down-voted because of poor formatting etc, I would only up-vote if the post has since been edited to the point that it deserves an up-vote.

Answer (score 5):

What prompts you to up-vote a post should not be a down-vote given from another user. Up-vote a post if you think it deserves an up-vote, and down-vote it if you think it deserves a down-vote.

The only *guide* to down-votes is given in the [privilege page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-down).

> #### When should I vote down?
>
> Use your down-votes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

While it can be a useful *guide*, it still is objective, since the privilege page is supposed to describe something that is true for every site.

In general, I would not down-vote a question simply because I know more than the user who asked the question, and I find the question not much helpful for me.

Comment: I'd also add that the "pity up-vote" (earning +5 or +10 rep) doesn't just counteract an "undeserved down-vote" (only -2 rep), but actually net *rewards* them for their content. When poorly-received content receives positive attention to counteract it, **you end up sending the *wrong* message** — you're encouraging *more* of that activity while actively ***discouraging*** the folks trying to point it out.

Comment: There's also guidance given when you mouseover the down arrow.  The messages are "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" and "This answer is not useful"

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no "correct" way to vote.

Everybody has their own standards, and since voting is (properly) anonymous, there's no way to enforce a Community standard. Quite the contrary: the standard is derived from the votes.

For what it's worth (not much: 0.0646% of the electorate, at this writing, and bound to decrease), my own practise is to upvote questions which elicit useful answers, regardless of formal 'quality', on the principle that the answers are what people come here for. This may distress many others who follow a different practise; but they may counteract my votes with their own. That's how a standard emerges.

Comment: I agree: Questions should also be _judged_ basing on the possible answers. A question for which there is much to be said should not get too much up-votes. Still, that is not the only possible criterion: If a user asks questions for which half of the times somebody comments with "You should not use that phrase in everyday usage." then probably that user is asking not so much interesting questions.

Answer (score 2):

Give a question an upvote if you think it deserves an upvote. And downvote it if you think it deserves a downvote.

When you try to second guess "meanings" into votes or start concentrating too hard on the total vote count of a question it means you've stopped judging the question based on its own merit.

In fact, it means that you've decided to vote, not based on what ***you*** think the question deserves, but based on what ***other people*** (i.e. neither yourself, nor the questioner/answerer) thinks.

The count of votes is nothing other than a way of saying whether more people think the post is useful than think it is unuseful. By artificially voting upwards or downwards you devalue that metric.

Take this meta question for example. At the time of me posting, the question has +2/-2.

Now if votes are working properly, this means that two people agree with the sentiment of your post, and two disagree. That's an interesting thing to know. It means people care about the question enough to vote, but there is no clear consensus in either direction.

But suppose that votes are being cast because people think the question doesn't "deserve" a negative score. Well in that case, perhaps two people disagree with your post, nobody agrees with it, and two people just thought the post didn't deserve a negative score.

In this system, it's much harder to derive anything useful out of the vote-count. Suddenly the vote count goes from being a quick-glance usefulness-indicator into being a meaningless number that takes up a lot of space on the side of a question.

As StoneyB points out, there is no one way to vote. You can vote because you like the question, appreciate the fact that it was asked, or because it made you think. Just don't vote for it because you want to "skew" the numbers upwards or downwards.

Doing so not only devalues the metric, it also devalues the up-votes you give to questions because they actually deserve it. You can only vote once on a question, so if one has -1, you can't vote it up "to cancel the negative vote" and another time "because it's a good question".

So, no. In my opinion, votes should be reserved for you to give your judgement on a question or answer that is good enough quality (for whatever reason) to deserve the vote.

Comment: I don't agree with your conclusion. The reason, as StoneyB points out, is because different votes have been cast for different reasons. If I don't agree with one specific reason, I think it's good I use my vote to oppose to that reason and prevent that reason becoming a standard (regardless of the value of the answer).